# Best infrastructure for a situation

Tags: .net, database, infrastructure

I have the following situation, and I'd like to know what approach would you take to solve this problem.

Here's the client needs.

He needs a WebSite / E-Commerce and what to be able to customize the look of the e-commerce. He also wants to be able to extend some functionality like product configuration.

He have an office in one country, and another office in another country.

The client make their order via the web or by phone, then someone in the company decide if the order should be done in office 1 or office 2.

The client needs to be able to see the information about the two offices from one location.

So we have 1 website + 2 office and I'd like to know what would you choose to do in this situation. Would you make everything in web, in that case, how can I handle barcode and special printers.

Would you do a website + 1 software that share a database on the web. In that case, would the data transfer be too slow.

The goal is to keep the development as simple as possible, because the client wants to be able to change the programmer if it is needed.

Preferably, the application should be done in .Net to make this easier to code.

So what would you do in this situation ?

Answer (score 2):

I would use web services for this to perform your operations against the data, but use a rich client to access the web services from the two offices.  This way, you can handle hardware that might be used in the offices, but not worry about connections to the database across the web (which is not a good thing).